# Inputing mathematical formula into java

Tags: java

I am having a problem I have not been able to solve searching the internet, basically I need the user to input first the diameter of a sphere then get back the radius and from there use the formula (4 over 3 multiplied by pi (3.14) multiplied by radius (calculated from diameter - user inputted) to the power of 3.
and the other one is very similar..... 4 multiplies by pi (3.14) multiplied by radius to the power of 2.

Now the thing is every time I try to compile I get errors that the method is lossy double not int or the symbol is not recognized.

guys any help would be helpful since I cant find a solution for this.

the code is below :

```
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class RadiusConverter {

    public class Pi{
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int FirstStep, Diameter, Radius, SecondStep, ThirdStep;

        System.out.println ("Please enter the diameter of the Sphere: ");

        int diameter =scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("Your Shpere has a radius of: " + FirstStep);

        int radius = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("The Volume of your Sphere is: " + SecondStep);

        System.out.println("The Surface Area of your Sphere is: " + ThirdStep);

        FirstStep = Diameter / 2;
        SecondStep =  4 / 3 * 3.14 * (int) FirstStep * 3;
        ThirdStep = 4 * 3.14 * (int) Radius * 2;
        Diameter = diameter;
        Radius = radius;
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you think `4 / 3` evaluates to? What do you think which type the expression `4 / 3 * 3.14 * (int) FirstStep * 3` has?

Comment: all your variables should be double instead of int. Why had two variables diameter and Diameter. You are printing FirstStep before even computing it.

Comment: I've tried using the Math.pi and Math.pow and I still get errors......

Comment: yeah so. … I first used all doubles, still errors, and when I used diameters .. I would get a cant recognise symbol error.

Comment: so here is the old code I used....which also did not compile.

Comment: this is the error I get when inputing the old code below : error: method pow in class Math cannot be applied to given types;

Answer (score 0):

```
      This is the older source code I was using … which also did not work.


      import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
      import static java.lang.Math.abs;
      import java.lang.*;
      import java.util.Scanner;
       import java.util.*;
      public class RadiusConverter
     {

  public class Pi{
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

    double FirstStep, Diameter, Radius, SecondStep, ThirdStep;


 System.out.println ("Please enter the diameter of the Sphere: ");
 double diameter =scan.nextDouble();


 System.out.println ("Your Shpere has a radius of: " + FirstStep);
 double radius =scan.nextDouble();


 System.out.println ("The Volume of your Sphere is: " + SecondStep);

 System.out.println("The Surface Area of your Sphere is: " + ThirdStep);

 FirstStep = diameter / 2;
 SecondStep =  4 / 3 * Math.PI* Math.pow (FirstStep, 3);
 ThirdStep = 4 * Math.PI * radius * Math.pow (2);


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    scan.close();


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try out this one

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RadiusConverter {

    public class Pi {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int firstStep = 0, diameter = 0, radius = 0, secondStep = 0, thirdStep = 0;
            System.out.print("Please enter the diameter of the Sphere: ");
            diameter = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Please enter the radius of the Sphere: ");
            radius = scan.nextInt();

            firstStep = diameter / 2;
            secondStep = (int) (4 / 3 * 3.14 * firstStep * 3);
            thirdStep = (int) (4 * 3.14 * radius * 2);

            System.out.println("Your Shpere has a radius of: " + firstStep);
            System.out.println("The Volume of your Sphere is: " + secondStep);
            System.out.println("The Surface Area of your Sphere is: " + thirdStep);
        }
    }
}
```

> Output

```
Please enter the diameter of the Sphere: 250
Please enter the radius of the Sphere: 25
Your Shpere has a radius of: 125
The Volume of your Sphere is: 1177
The Surface Area of your Sphere is: 628
```

Comment: Thank You so much man..it worked. Again thank you for your help. I see where I made errors but also some people where telling me to make everything double not int. Thank You again Chirag your a gentlemen.

Comment: If you want them in double, remove the int cast and change `int` to `double` in variable declarations.